# trigger react-ace onChange via React Testing Library (RTL)

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor, react-testing-library, react-ace

in my code, i have component that using react-ace.
in my render function i have this row:

```
<CodeEditor onChange={onCodeChanged} value={code} />
```

callback function:

```
const onCodeBodyChanged = (newCode) => {
      // some code ...
      dispatch(setResource({ newCode }));
}
```

I want to test `onCodeChanged` via RTL, so I tried to find the text area on change the value, but without any success

example of (not working) test:

```
      const { container } = render(<ResourceEditorPanel />, createMockStore());
      const ace = container.querySelectorAll('.ace_text-input');
      fireEvent.change(ace, { target: { value: 'someText' } });
      await waitFor(() => {
        expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
```

the problem is `fireEvent.change(ace, { target: { value: 'someText' } });` doesn't trigger my function - onCodeChanged.

Do you know how can I test it?

Answer (score 1):

I spent far too much time on this :/ in the end my issue was a small one. The element that should have the data pasted into it is the class "ace_content". The following worked for me.

```
const editorInputField = container.querySelector('[class="ace_content"]') as Element;

fireEvent.click(editorInputField);

await userEvent.click(editorInputField);
await userEvent.paste('{ "name": "Test" }')
```

Comment: `fireEvent.click(editorInputField);` was not necessary for me.

Comment: A note to those who come here looking for a solution to their problem, the API of `UserEvent.paste` has changed in testing-library v14 (from `paste(element, text)` to `paste(text)`); make sure to click or focus the element you want to paste into.

Answer (score -1):

Ace editor awaits for an input event so you'll also need to fire something like `fireEvent(ace, new Event('input'))`